# Can't install php55-apcu on Homebrew

Tags: php, homebrew, apc, command-line-interface

I don't know if this is a problem with the package, or a problem with my machine. I keep trying to install the package, but all I can get is:

```
==> Installing php55-apcu from homebrew/homebrew-php
==> Installing dependencies for php55-apcu: php55, pcre
==> Installing php55-apcu dependency: php55
==> Downloading https://www.php.net/get/php-5.5.20.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/php55-5.5.20
Warning: Backing up all known pear.conf and .pearrc files
Warning: If you have a pre-existing pear install outside
     of homebrew-php, or you are using a non-standard
     pear.conf location, installation may fail.
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.20 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php
==> make
```

At "make", nothing happens and my machine just starts overheating. Where is the problem here?

Comment: How long are you leaving it, and what happens with `brew install -vd php55-apcu`?

Comment: Waiting about 5 minutes. I'll try waiting a little longer, and running `brew install -vd php55-apcu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you aren't waiting long enough. To install php55-apcu, Homebrew also has to compile PHP 5.5, which takes some time.

If you want to see what's happening in more detail, add the `--verbose` option to your `brew install` command.